# Old & New Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like below.

```
 EmpName   Sta_CD   Comments
 AAAAAA     1        One
 AAAAAA     2        two
 AAAAAA     2        two_Updated
 AAAAAA     2        two_UpdatedAgain
 AAAAAA     3        Three
 AAAAAA     4        Four
```

I am trying to track Old and New Values of Sta_CD for Employee, Like Below one.

```
 EmpName Old_Sta_CD   Sta_CD   Comments
 AAAAAA      Null        1        One
 AAAAAA       1          2        two
 AAAAAA       2          2        two_Updated
 AAAAAA       2          2        two_UpdatedAgain
 AAAAAA       2          3        Three
 AAAAAA       3          4        Four
```

Can AnyOne Suggest me how to get this output?

Comment: How do you know that an entry is "older" than another ? Especially when Sta_CD is the same ? I mean why two_UpdatedAgain > two_Updated > two, if you have no "date" or id to order by ?

Comment: If you are trying to keep an audit or history I would seriously consider looking at [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx) It works and there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to do this, something like:

```
WITH Ranked
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sta_CD) AS RN
  FROM table1
)
SELECT 
  old.EmpName,
  new.Sta_CD AS Old_Sta_CD,
  old.Sta_CD,
  old.Comments
FROM Ranked AS old
LEFT JOIN Ranked AS new ON old.rn - 1 = new.rn;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc3eeb/4)

This will give you:

```
| EMPNAME | OLD_STA_CD | STA_CD |         COMMENTS |
|---------|------------|--------|------------------|
|  AAAAAA |     (null) |      1 |              One |
|  AAAAAA |          1 |      2 |              two |
|  AAAAAA |          2 |      2 |      two_Updated |
|  AAAAAA |          2 |      2 | two_UpdatedAgain |
|  AAAAAA |          2 |      3 |            Three |
|  AAAAAA |          3 |      4 |             Four |
```

Comment: Wouldn't a "partition by EmpName" be necessary ? Looks like sample data, but I would guess you could have different EmpName...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - Yes, you are right, also the ordering is not clear. The sample data is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+`

Use **[LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh231256.aspx)** Function to get the previous row

```
SELECT EmpName,
       Lag(sta_cd)
         OVER(
           partition BY empname
           ORDER BY Sta_CD)old_Sta_CD,
       Sta_CD,
       Comments
FROM   <tablename>
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86b8a/2)**